# What is a Number Word™?

Tags: word-property, language, english

This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Number Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| NUMBER WORDS™ | NOT NUMBER WORDS™ |
| --- | --- |
| unincorporated | unorganized |
| rabies | canker |
| triangulate | dissever |
| quadratics | polynomial |
| unrepentant | remorseless |
| cathexes | ardency |
| decentralize | suburbanize |
| orchiectomy | sterilization |

Here is a CSV Version:

```
NUMBER WORDS™, NOT NUMBER WORDS™
unincorporated, unorganized
rabies, canker
triangulate, dissever
quadratics, polynomial
unrepentant, remorseless
cathexes, ardency
decentralize, suburbanize
orchiectomy, sterilization
```

Something I forgot to note:

There is no I in orchiectomy.

Comment: I believe that text shouldn't be spoilered, because it is necessary to be sure you've solved the puzzle. It's not just a hint, it's an important inconsistency that should be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Number Word™ is

> a word with a Latin number prefix in it: **uni**ncorporated, ra**bi**es, **tri**angulate, **quad**ratics, unre**pent**ant, cat**hex**es, de**cent**ralize, orc**h**i**ecto**my. (This last one seems to be a bit inconsistent, and would also make "su**b**urban**i**ze" a Number Word as well, though...)

Comment: Suburbanize is not a Number Word because the letters b and i are not together.

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison Then "orchiectomy" should not be a Number Word either. You can choose to allow nonconsecutive substrings or disallow them, but you should be consistent.

Comment: I just noticed and the correct spelling was orchectomy.